# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pyerp-master/installed_apps.py'

Tags: django

When i was installing pyerp I got this error.

```html
2021-10-14 10:55:11,449 - DEBUG -settings.py:24 - hello world!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/erronny/running workspace/python/django/pyerp-master/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/erronny/running workspace/python/django/pyerp-master/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/erronny/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/erronny/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 325, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/erronny/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/erronny/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/erronny/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/erronny/running workspace/python/django/pyerp-master/pyerp/settings.py", line 80, in <module>
    with open('%s/installed_apps.py' % BASE_DIR, 'r') as ins_apps_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/pyerp-master/installed_apps.py'
```

I follow github instruction from here
[github](https://github.com/falconsoft3d/pyerp)

And i got stucked never found a specific solution i founds after long time and searching on google but it took to much time.

Answer (score 0):

I was following this step

```html
virtualenv env --python=python3
source env/bin/activate
cd pyerp
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
python3 manage.py init_pyerp
python3 manage.py runserver
```

I installed all requirement from `requirements.txt` file

Then i got this above error. I just created a file in root folder name `installed_apps.py`

Then

```
python3 manage.py init_pyerp
```

Then `python3 manage.py runserver`